# How to increment a counter when a value is found in awk

Tags: awk, scripting

I am trying to write an awk script. part of the code needs to count the number of times $10 (in the code below its 256) is a certain value. 
The possibilities are 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256
Each time one of these values appears I want a corresponding variable to be incremented by one.

My block of code is

```
{
if ($10 == "4") {bs_4k++} 
else if ($10 == "8") {bs_8k++}
if ($10 == "16") {bs_16k++}
if ($10 == "32") {bs_32k++}
if ($10 == "64") {bs_64k++}
if ($10 == "128") {bs_128k++}
if ($10 == "256") {bs_256k++}
};
```

This is the format of the data:

```
259,0   23        1     0.000000000     0  C  WS 167588096 + 256 [0]
259,0   23        2     0.000002073     0  C  WS 167588352 + 256 [0]
259,0   23        3     0.000004040     0  C  WS 167587840 + 256 [0]
```

And my code to print results:

```
END {
     print "Number of 256k blocks: " 256k_bs;
     print "Number of 128k blocks: "128k_bs;
     print "Number of 64k blocks: " 64k_bs;
     print "Number of 32k blocks: " 32k_bs;
     print "Number of 16k blocks: " 16k_bs;
     print "Number of 8k blocks: " 8k_bs;
     print "Number of 4k blocks: " 4k_bs;
};
```

When I try to print the variable I get:

```
Number of 256k blocks: 256
Number of 128k blocks: 128
Number of 64k blocks: 64
Number of 32k blocks: 32
Number of 16k blocks: 16
Number of 8k blocks: 8
Number of 4k blocks: 4
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure exactly why this question earned a downvote. I think it clearly demonstrates the need for help, and expresses the problem and goal sufficiently for answers to be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using your variables in the `END` block. As such, the numeric part is being interpreted literally, then a variable `k_bs` is being evaluated (which is unset, so you get an empty string).

Change `256k_bs` to `bs_256k`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to hadnle this in awk might be to use an array instead of a collection of distinct variables.

Using this awk script:

```
BEGIN{
  for (i=4;i<=256;i=i*2) { valid[i] }
}

$10 in valid {
  bs[$10]++
}

END {
  for (n in bs) {
    printf("Number of %dk blocks: %d\n", n, bs[n])
  }
}
```

on the following input data:

```
259,0 23 1 0.000000000 0 C WS 167588096 + 256 [0]
259,0 23 2 0.000002073 0 C WS 167588352 + 256 [0]
259,0 23 3 0.000004040 0 C WS 167587840 + 256 [0]
259,0 23 3 0.000004040 0 C WS 167587000 + 32 [0]
259,0 23 3 0.000004040 0 C WS 167587001 + 64 [0]
```

gets me the following results:

```
$ awk -f i.awk input.txt
Number of 64k blocks: 1
Number of 32k blocks: 1
Number of 256k blocks: 3
```

Of course, if you want the output sorted, you can pipe it through sort, or structure your awk array differently. Such additions are left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Comment: This is really sexy, I need to learn about arrays (I'm still learning scripting).  Thank you very much for your reply

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve the same with unit toolset

```
$ cut -d' ' -f10 file | sort -nr | uniq -c

  3 256
  1 64
  1 32
```

and format the result as desired.

Comment: Unfortunately this wont work for me. The problem I present here is just a small portion of what I am trying to do with the data and I can't accomplish the rest with bash (or better said, I haven't the time to learn how to do it with shell utilities).